# What are the major differences between apache spark and clickhouse? And how to choose between them?

Tags: apache-spark, compare, clickhouse

I know that **clickhouse** is a **column-oriented database** that can serve **OLAP purposes**. However, it seems that both spark and clickhouse support distributed computing, columnar storage( parquet files in case of spark), in-memory processing , sql-based, and some other fatures (index, partition..). Can anbody please explain in which cases should I use spark over clickhouse and vice versa in a big data architecture?Thanks

Comment: Both are different products. Spark is a distributed processing framework/engine and Clickhouse is a distributed column-oriented DBMS. Both can have some common functionalities but the use cases and problems they solve are entirely different.

Comment: Can you give me some examples of the use cases and problems where spark is preferred over clickhouse and vice vesa? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The choice between ClickHouse or Apache Spark depends on the desired results.

1. **Data Type and Volume:** ClickHouse is optimized for analytics on structured data, while Spark handles various data types and processing needs. For instance, if you need to work with semi-structured or unstructured data, then Spark is the preferred choice. However, if dealing with CSV or other structured data types, ClickHouse is more suitable.
2. **Real-time Processing:** ClickHouse is notably fast, but Spark surpasses it in terms of real-time performance. If your task involves real-time operations such as streaming or similar tasks, then Spark is the more appropriate option.